# Java Constructors and Null Pointer Exceptions

Tags: java, constructor, nullpointerexception

I am playing around with java, and have run into an issue when I utilize custom constructors.

When I begin my program, the main file contains a line like this:

```
Word input = new Word(word);
```

The constructor for word looks like this:

```
public Word(String s){
        wordArray = s.toCharArray(); 
        protocol = new Protocol(wordArray.length);
    }
```

And the protocol looks like this:

```
public Protocol(int length)
    {
        letterList[0] = 'a';
        letterList[1] = 'b';
        letterList[2] = 'c';
        letterList[3] = 'd';
        letterList[4] = 'e';
        letterList[5] = 'f';
        letterList[6] = 'g';
        letterList[7] = 'h';
        letterList[8] = 'i';
        letterList[9] = 'j';
        letterList[10] = 'k';
        letterList[11] = 'l';
        letterList[12] = 'm';
        letterList[13] = 'n';
        letterList[14] = 'o';
        letterList[15] = 'p';
        letterList[16] = 'q';
        letterList[17] = 'r';
        letterList[18] = 's';
        letterList[19] = 't';
        letterList[20] = 'u';
        letterList[21] = 'v';
        letterList[22] = 'w';
        letterList[23] = 'x';
        letterList[24] = 'y';
        letterList[25] = 'z';
        wordLength = length;
        for(int i=0;i<wordLength*2-1;i++)
        {
            display[i] = '_';
            i++;
            display[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` at the line within my main file where `word` is constructed, and then `protocol` .

I have experimented with the code, and noticed if I do not call the constructor for the `protocol` within `word` the build is successful past that point, but I need protocol to be built later as well, so it still has issues.

Am I not allowed to call a constructor within another constructor? Anyone have any ideas on what may be going on?

If you need more clarification, please let me know!

Comment: So what's the value of `s` you're passing?

Comment: You dont need an array of letters, you can just use `a + index`.

Comment: @Swapnil as if you need to ask. **Clearly: `null`!**

Comment: Please post the stack trace and indicate or post the exact line of code referred to at the top of the stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I not allowed to call a constructor within another constructor?

No, you are *definitely* allowed to do that.

> Anyone have any ideas on what may be going on?

Clearly, `word` is `null` when passed to the `Word` constructor at this line:

```
Word input = new Word(word);
```

Comment: I agree this  is the simple answer. However, in lines above the word constructor, I call `System.out.println(word)`, and it prints the word as expected. Thoughts?

Comment: Then as Abu suggested, you may have failed to initialize `letterList`.

Comment: Then step through your code with a debugger, and see what variable or field is `null` that your code is trying to dereference.

Comment: Ah! I found it! Good call on the failure to initialize. I have another array which I failed to initialize after the letterList. After I fixed the first I didn't notice the line number change until I went back a few times! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be because you might not have initialized you `letterList` array, so try initializing it first before using it.

```
public Protocol(int length)
{
   letterList = new char[26];  
   letterList[0] = 'a';  
   letterList[1] = 'b';  
   letterList[2] = 'c';  
   ...  
   ...

}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is another possible issue. +1